# Update WPF control when event fires

Tags: wpf, user-interface, binding

I have a class which monitors a log file. It will fire an event when a new line is added.

What is the proper way, to update multiple controls in WPF?

Keep in mind that I am new to WPF bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about bindings and MVVM. In MVVM you can have your viewmodel class implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) allowing the view to be automatically updated when a binding property in viewmodel class is updated. In your case your viewmodel can subscribe to the fired event and update a property which in turn will update the view (controls).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So if I have a ListBox, I should create a List in my viewmodel class and set the DataContext for the ListBox to the viewmodel class. Is this correct?

Comment: There is actually ItemsSource Property in ListBox that you can bind your collection too. I would use ObservableCollection (instead of List) so the ListBox is updated when the collection is updated.